# Eclipse get method list with subword

Tags: eclipse, list, methods, filter

I'm using the Eclipse method list feature for navigation that is triggered by `ctrl + o` shortcut. In addition, there is a filter that performs an exact method name match. This can be sometimes annoying if you look out for a certain property and don't start with get oder set. Can this be adjusted to perform subword matching? As it is performed with Code Recommenders?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem on this [site](http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2011/02/21/the-easiest-ways-to-navigate-methods-in-a-class-using-eclipse-keyboard-shortcuts/). Being able to list all method with the Quick Outline view that contain index, use *index as search term.

[image]